# Sound not coming through amp

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I was playing my guitar earlier today, everything working fine; sound coming through the amp and all.

I bought new strings strings and changed them out today and moved the guitar and amp into to a different place, but now when I play the guitar it doesn't come through the amp.

I have a brand new guitar cord, and used another to see if it would work, but nothing worked. It isn't the amp because it is turned on and when I unplug the cord from the guitar then put my finger on it it makes noise the way it would.

The only problem I could see would be with the guitar, although nothing has happened to it. 
What could the problem be?

Comment: Ok at the risk of being mildly insulting, you made sure the guitar volume is all the way up, right? If so, the most likely wire to have come loose is one of the wires leading to the output jack. If you don't know how to use a soldering iron, I'd recommend taking it to a shop.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you have done the simple checks, and if you get a hum from touching the jack that rules out cable and amp (aside from a couple of exceptional faults.)

Do as Todd suggests, and try turning the knobs full range while the cable is plugged in and seeing if strumming generates any sounds from the amp. Also check to see if any of the pots are pull/push.

Next step is to unscrew the plate holding the jack socket on to your guitar. This varies between guitar types, but is often a small metal plate with a couple of screws, like this one from [strat-talk](http://www.strat-talk.com/forum/stratocaster-discussion-forum/206045-output-jack-problems.html).

[image]

When you pull this carefully away from the guitar, you should see two wires connected to it - the most common things that go are either that one of these has come loose or the springy bit has bent back and no longer touches the jack.

If it looks fine, the next thing to check is wires going to your volume and tone pots - these may require a different plate to be unscrewed; sometimes it's the scratch plate, sometimes you get at these from the back etc., but again, you are looking for a wire that isn't connected any more.

Soldering wires back on is straightforward if you have done it before, but if not, the thing to remember is that soldering a wire to a chunk of metal (like the output jack) requires the metal to get quite hot in order to make a good connection, so be careful. If in any doubt, take it to your local guitar shop.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of sounding like a complete dolt: did you use strings for electric guitar?  Because if not, the magnetic pickups will just fail to "see" them.

Answer (score 0):

The jack of the Strat ussually has issues, in the following article ([Improve / upgrade a guitar](https://guitarriego.com/en-us/guides/best-tips-and-tricks-for-improving-a-cheap-electric-guitar/))there is a lot of tips and one include to change the jack of the strat.

Comment: Hi Fred, welcome to Music.SE! Would you be able to summarize that article for us in your answer? This way we can still have the information should the link ever die out.

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this is that the amplifier may be going into what's called "protect mode." This happens when the amplifier gets too hot and shuts itself off to prevent damage. If this is the case, you'll need to give the amplifier time to cool down before turning it back on.

Another possibility is that the power supply to the amplifier has become disrupted. This can happen if there's a loose wire or connection somewhere. Try unplugging and then replugging in all of the wires to make sure they're secure.

If the problem is with the speakers, it could be that they're not properly plugged in or that the wires have become loose. Again, try unplugging and replugging everything to make sure the connections are tight. Check - [Why Not Working AMP?](https://windowscommand-line.com/subwoofer-not-working-amp-has-power/)

If you still can't get the sound to come through, it's possible that the amplifier itself is damaged and will need to be replaced.